# Difference between 'will' and 'would'

Tags: will-would

The following is an excerpt from a newspaper.

> *In situations where the father has not exhibited any concern for his
>   offspring giving him legal recognition **would** be an exercise in
>   futility.*

Why does the author use *would* and not *will*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this instance, the author uses 'would' as they are speaking about a hypothetical possibility; it is not something that has actually happened. Whereas, using 'will' implies that this has, or shall soon be, taking place, and is a certainty rather than a probability.

Answer (score 1):

user128193 is correct.
For better explanation, I would like to add  that *would* is a past form of *will* and is often used:

- in auxiliary functions with rather to express preference

> I *would* rather go shopping today.
>   We *would* rather say something than
>   stay quiet.

- to express a wish or desire

> I *would* like to have one more pencil.

- to express contingency or possibility

> If I were you, I *would* be so happy.

- to express routine or habitual things

> Normally, we *would* work until 6 p.m.

So as what user128193 explained, your example is used to express contingency or possibility.

For more info about auxuliary verbs, try to check [Talk English](http://www.talkenglish.com).

Answer (score -3):

We use will:
to talk about the future – to say what we believe will happen

would is the past tense form of will. 
Because it is a past tense it is used:
to talk about the past.